# Unable to execute IndexOutOfBounds exception while iterating dropdown with webtable

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, automation

Here my code is unable to execute because of an `IndexOutOfBounds` error. I have to automate iteration dropdown including webtable for every selection of dropdown. I have to edit in webtable.

Can u help me for this situation?

```
    s = new Select(ledger.SelectPayrollCategoriesLedger);
     List<WebElement> led=s.getOptions();
     int ledselectsize=led.size();
     for(int i=0;i<ledselectsize;i++) {
     WebElement select=led.get(i);
     select.click();
     Thread.sleep(1500);
     int editactionsize=ledger.EditActionBtnLedger.size();
    System.out.println("edit size is: "+editactionsize);
    for(int j=0;j<editactionsize;j++) {

            try {
                editac=ledger.EditActionBtnLedger.get(j);
                editac.click();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                editac = ledger.EditActionBtnLedgerStale.get(j);
                editac.click();
            }   
    }   
}
```

It is showing the exception in:

```
editac = ledger.EditActionBtnLedgerStale.get(j);
```

Comment: Well, you should check which index is out of bounds. From your (poorly formatted) code it looks like the most likely part is `ledger.EditActionBtnLedgerStale.get(j)` (because `EditActionBtnLedgerStale` might be smaller than `EditActionBtnLedger`). However, if the lists you're accessing could change concurrently, i.e. while your thread is executing, then the others could be problematic as well: as an example `ledselectsize` would have a defined value but if the size of `led` changes during iteration the call `led.get(i)` might fail - better use `i<led.size()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that size of

```
 ledger.EditActionBtnLedgerStale
```

is same as that of size of

```
 ledger.EditActionBtnLedger
```

please check whether below code will work for you,

```
for(int j=0;j<editactionsize;j++) {

        try {
            editac=ledger.EditActionBtnLedger.get(j);
            editac.click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(ledger.EditActionBtnLedgerStale.size() > j){
               editac=ledger.EditActionBtnLedgerStale.get(j);
               editac.click();
           }
        }   
}
```

It will help to avoid IndexOutOfBounds.